# gcc-12/13: std::stacktrace is still not found

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-22.04, c++23

I have this code:

```
#include <stacktrace>
#include <iostream>

int nested_func(int c)
{
    std::cout << std::stacktrace::current() << '\n';
    return c + 1;
}

int func(int b)
{
    return nested_func(b + 1);
}
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << func(777);
}
```

I install gcc-12 and gcc-13 by following on ubuntu22.04

```
sudo apt install gcc-13 g++-13
sudo apt install gcc-12 g++-12
```

Then I try to compile the code:

```
g++-13 -std=c++23 -lstdc++_libbacktrace test.cpp
```

Yet I get following error for both gcc-12 and gcc-13

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int nested_func(int)’:
test.cpp:6:23: error: ‘std::stacktrace’ has not been declared
    6 |     std::cout << std::stacktrace::current() << '\n';
      |
```

Comment: The C++23 standard is still very new, and it might not be fully implemented yet. Read more here: [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Comment: seems that this feature is supported though

Comment: Works [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ojcT5Tzjx).  not sure what your issue is though

Comment: True, it works on gotbolt when using gcc12 but not 13. When you sudo apt install it on ubuntu 22.04 both versions won't compile

Comment: I'd guess though you're using a new version of gcc you're still using the system default version of libstdc++

Comment: Per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23), for GCC 12/13 you need to build to _compiler_ (not the program) with `--enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes` and _then_ link with `-lstdc++_libbacktrace`. For GCC 14, it's enabled by default, but you need to link against `-lstdc++exp`.

Comment: I should add that for gcc-13 you would need only lstdc++exp as the former you mentioned ceased to exists. However, that gives a linkage error even when configuring the compiler build with backtrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments, this is probably because your distribution does not fully support c++23 yet. Thus, the `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_STACKTRACE` checked in the header `<stacktrace>` is not set.

Comment: can you perhaps guide how to set `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_STACKTRACE`

Comment: @ATK I'd imagine you'd have to set that when building libstdc++ from source